# why the element not appending in linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

not getting expected output. Missing node with data = 6
looks like not insertAfter method properly,
cant find the issue.
pls suggest any other issue too as i am just started with data structures. is there anything need to be kept in mind while studying data structures.

```
  class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkeList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def push(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head  = new_node

    def insertAfter(self,prev_node,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        new_node.next = prev_node.next
        prev_node.next = new_node

    def append(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        last = self.head
        while last.next != None:
            last = last.next
        last.next = new_node

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.data, end = " ")
            temp = temp.next

if __name__ =='__main__':
    llist = LinkedList()
    llist.append(7)

    llist.append(8)

    llist.push(5)

    llist.insertAfter(Node(5),6)
    llist.printList()
```

Comment: `insertAfter` isn't correct. You aren't modifying any of the nodes in the list, just two completely new nodes that become unreachable after the function returns

Comment: The `Node(5)` in `llist.insertAfter(Node(5),6)` isn't a node in your linked list. It's a node you just created with no connection to your list.

Comment: how to mention node with data = 5?

Comment: If you want to get the node with the value 5 from your linked list, you'll have to iterate through your linked list and find it.

Comment: if your API assumes that the `prev_node` is supposed to be a node in the list, then you must have some reference to that node that you pass into the function. Usually, you would provide a value, and search for a node with that value instead

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is in this line,

`llist.insertAfter(Node(5),6)`

When you do insertAfter then you need to first get a Node from the current linked list, rather what you are doing is, that you create a new node, then pass it. That new node might have the same value as a . node in your linked list, but it really isn't a part of it, what you need to do is as follows

First implement a get node function, that gets a node from the linked list with the value that you want, something like this

```
def getNode(self, value):
    temp = self.head
    while temp is not None:
        if temp.value == value:
            return temp
        else:
            temp = temp.next

    return None
```

then do this.

`llist.insertAfter(llist.getNode(5),6)`

Also put a check for if passed node is not None in insertAfter